# iText 7 creating editable field with embedded font cannot see typing

Tags: itext7

How do I solve the issue? When I create a font that's not embedded, I create an editable text box using the following code.

```
var myPdfField = PdfTextFormField.CreateText(pdfDoc, textBoxRect, sAssignedName).SetFont(fieldFont).SetVisibility(PdfFormField.VISIBLE);
```

When I type into the PDF field, I see the text that's typed and all works as expected

When I embed the font in the PDF, I cannot see the text typed into the field. I've used multiple methods to create the font and a couple to add the text box with the same results. This is how I currently create the font.

```
fontPgmTimes = FontProgramFactory.CreateFont(sFontTimes);
timesFontBold = timesFontNorm = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(fontPgmTimes, PdfEncodings.WINANSI, true);
```

If I type into the filed with the font embedded and exit the PDF without saving, it prompts me to save the changes. If I back out the changes, there is no prompting. Therefore, I think the text is entered into the field and I cannot see it on the screen.

Added 2018.05.01
I've discovered that adding text to the text field changes the behavior. Each character entered in the text field may be used as new text. For example, adding text "abcABCdef789.,-" as shown

```
var myPdfField = PdfTextFormField.CreateText(pdfDoc, textBoxRect, sAssignedName, "abcABCdef789.,-").SetFont(fieldFont).SetVisibility(PdfFormField.VISIBLE);
```

allows the user to type any number of characters so long as they are limited to those in the initial text. The default behavior is as though an empty string, "", were entered as text.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you create an embedded PDF font in iText 7, it by default only embeds the subset of the definitions of *actually used* glyphs into the document. You observed this yourself when you added an initial value in your field:

```
var myPdfField = PdfTextFormField.CreateText(pdfDoc, textBoxRect, sAssignedName, "abcABCdef789.,-").SetFont(fieldFont).SetVisibility(PdfFormField.VISIBLE);
```

As the glyphs of the characters `"abcABCdef789.,-"` (and only they) were used by iText (to create the appearance of the field), they constituted the subset of glyphs of your font that was embedded.

If you want to embed the whole font to allow the user to input any glyphs from your font instead, you have to disable subsetting:

```
fieldFont.SetSubset(false);
```

(Do this as early as possible after generating the `fieldFont` font to prevent iText from erroneously starting to create a subset.)

If you want to embed predefined ranges of glyphs from the font (e.g. if your defined encoding does not encompass the whole set of font glyphs anyway), you can do it like this:

```
fieldFont.SetSubset(false);
fieldFont.AddSubsetRange(new int[] { 32, 255 });
```

(Once again, do this as early as possible after generating the `fieldFont` font to prevent iText from erroneously starting to create a custom subset.)

This might look a bit weird because you first "set Subset to `false`" and then "add a Subset range". If one considers the meaning of `SetSubset` to be "enable creation of a custom subset of used glyphs only", though, it makes sense.

This, by the way, corresponds to the documentation of the `SetSubset` method.